# Problems with comparison in prolog's rules

Tags: prolog

I'm new in Prolog and I create a small base wit "car" statements.

```
car(ford, mondeo, 125600, 31000).
car(ford, mondeo, 111232, 35000).
car(renault, megane, 82000, 28000).
car(renault, laguna, 102000, 35000).
car(renault, laguna, 82000, 42000).
car(www, pasat, 82000, 42000).
car(renault, aaa, 82000, 428900).
```

How I can find all cars with >10000 third argument? I try write a rule in consol (!not in the file!) `?- car(Z,X,C > 10000,V).` but I get only `false` (but how? Prolog must print all cars, because all cars are match).

Comment: car(Z,X,C,V) := C > 10000.

Comment: @mazzy, ERROR: Undefined procedure: (:=)/2 (DWIM could not correct goal)

Comment: May be **car(Z,X,C,V) , C > 10000.**

Comment: @joel76, thx very much!

Comment: @magician-artemka, Sorry. Try `:-`. it may be `:-`, `:=`, `->`, `=>` depend on Prolog dialect.

Comment: `?- car(Z,X,C,V) , C > 10000.` if you want to ask a question. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`car(Z,X,C > 10000,V).` will not work, because prolog will try to unify each rule head with `car(Z,X,C > 10000,V).`, and it will fail for every one of those.

More in detail:

`car(ford, mondeo, 125600, 31000)` will fail to unify with `car(Z,X,C > 10000,V)`, because `125600` fails to unify with `C > 10000`.

Make sure to read and understand [how unification works](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse5).

The correct strategy is to exploit backtracking to filter results: you probably have noticed that entering the query `car(Z,X,C,V)` will return you all the cars' data.

If you add a further goal to that, it will have to go back when the second goal fail, and try another choice.

Continue the reading also with [proof search](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse6).

The second goal you should add to your query then is `C>10000`:

```
car(Z,X,C,V), C > 10000
```